# F# How to write a function that takes int list or string list

Tags: f#

I'm messing around in F# and tried to write a function that can take an `int list` or a `string list`. I have written a function that is logically generic, in that I can modify nothing but the type of the argument and it will run with both types of list. But I cannot generically define it to take both.

Here is my function, without type annotation:

```ml
let contains5 xs =
    List.map int xs
    |> List.contains 5
```

When I try to annotate the function to take a generic list, I receive a warning `FS0064: the construct causes the code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations`. In theory I shouldn't need to annotate this to be generic, but I tried anyway.

I can compile this in two separate files, one with

```ml
let stringtest = contains5 ["1";"2";"3";"4"]
```

and another with

```ml
let inttest = contains5 [1;2;3;4;5]
```

In each of these files, compilation succeeds. Alternately, I can send the function definition and one of the tests to the interpreter, and type inference proceeds just fine. If I try to compile, or send to the interpreter, the function definition and both tests, I receive `error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type string, but here has type int`.

Am I misunderstanding how typing should work? I have a function whose code can handle a list of ints or a list of strings. I can successfully test it with either. But I can't use it in a program that handles both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running into value restrictions on the automatic generalization of the type inference system as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/automatic-generalization)

Specifically,

> Case 4: Adding type parameters.

The solution is to make your function generic rather than just making its parameters generic.

```ml
let inline contains5< ^T when ^T : (static member op_Explicit: ^T -> int) > (xs : ^T list)  =
    List.map int xs
    |> List.contains 5
```

You have to make the function inline because you have to use a statically resolved type parameter, and you have to use a statically resolved type parameter in order to use member constraints to specify that the type must be convertible to an int. As outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `inline` to prevent the function from being fixed to a particular type.

In FSI, the interactive REPL:

```
> open System;;
> let inline contains5 xs = List.map int xs |> List.contains 5;;
val inline contains5 :
  xs: ^a list -> bool when  ^a : (static member op_Explicit :  ^a -> int)

> [1;2;3] |> contains5;;
val it : bool = false

> ["1";"2";"5"] |> contains5;;
val it : bool = true
```

Note that the signature of contains5 has a generic element to it. There's more about inline functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/inline-functions).

Answer (score 3):

This is already answered correctly above, so I just wanted to chime in with why I think it's a good thing that F# appears to makes this difficult / forces us to lose type safety. Personally I don't see these as logically equivalent:

```ml
let inline contains5 xs = List.map int xs |> List.contains 5

let stringTest = ["5.00"; "five"; "5"; "-5"; "5,"]
let intTest = [1;2;3;4;5]

contains5 stringTest // OUTPUT: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
contains5 intTest // OUTPUT: true
```

When inlined, the compiler would create two logically distinct versions of the function. When performed on the `list<int>` we get a boolean result. When performed on a `list<string>` we get a boolean result or an exception. I like that F# nudges me towards acknowledging this.

```ml
let maybeInt i = 
    match Int32.TryParse i with
    | true,successfullyParsedInteger -> Some successfullyParsedInteger
    | _ -> None

let contains5 xs = 
    match box xs with
    | :? list<int> as ixs -> 
        ixs |> List.contains 5 |> Ok
    | :? list<string> as sxs -> 
        let successList = sxs |> List.map maybeInt |> List.choose id
        Ok (successList |> List.contains 5)
    | _ -> 
        Error "Error - this function expects a list<int> or a list<string> but was passed something else."

let stringTest = ["5.00"; "five"; "5"; "-5"; "5,"]
let intTest = [1;2;3;4;5]

let result1 = contains5 stringTest // OUTPUT: Ok true
let result2 = contains5 intTest // OUTPUT: Ok true
```

Forces me to ask `if some of the values in the string list cannot be parsed, should I drop out and fail, or should I just try and look for any match on any successful parse results?`.

My approach above is horrible. I'd split the function that operates on the strings from the one that operates on the integers. I think your question was academic rather than a real use case though, so I hope I haven't gone off on too much of a tangent here!

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner, don't trust anything I say.

Comment: This is super helpful for me. I appreciate the time to share extra perspective. My question was, in fact, academic. If I needed to do this for real, I'd define a helper, similarly to how you've done above. I agree with you that it is important to address the question of what to do with a malformed input.